# How to export .trace file to a csv file in macOS High sierra

Tags: macos, export-to-csv, instruments, xcode-instruments

I'm new to ios Mobile automation. I have a .trace file  I am trying to convert the trace into a csv file or any readable format through commandline terminal i dont seem to find anything  in my macOS High Sierra version 10.13
Is there any other way I can convert the trace into a .csv file? any advise on this would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Any working example would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the `.trace` to `.csv` format within Instruments:

```
1. After profiling an app with a trace document, select the instrument containing 
   the data you want to export.

2. Choose Instrument > Export Track for instrument name.

3. Enter a name for the file.

4. Specify a destination for the file.
```

> <sub>***Note***:</sub> <sub>Exported data is designed to be shared with external apps, and not
>   re-imported into Instruments. If you want to save trace data in
>   Instruments format, you should save your trace document, along with
>   its collected results, so you can open it again later.</sub>

Instruments exports the data for the most recent run of the selected instrument.

↳ [Export and Import Trace Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/ExportingandImportingTraceData.html)

Comment: Could you please share any sample commands to do it through commandline

Comment: @syndy1989: There are no CLI commands, you export from the Instruments.app.

Comment: @syndy1989, I never mentioned anything regarding CLI commands; how does this not answer your question?

Comment: this feature to export csv has been removed